# Leetcode jumpgame recursive approach

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, nested-loops

Given the following problem:

> You are given an integer array nums. You are initially positioned at the array's first index, and each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that position.
>
> Return true if you can reach the last index, or false otherwise.

**Example 1:**

> Input: `nums = [2,3,1,1,4]`
>
> Output: `True`
>
> Explanation: Jump 1 step from index 0 to 1, then 3 steps to the last index.

**Example 2:**

> Input: `nums = [3,2,1,0,4]`
>
> Output: `False`
>
> Explanation: You will always arrive at index 3 no matter what. Its maximum jump length is 0, which makes it impossible to reach the last index.

I am trying to come up with a recursive solution. This is what I have so far. I am not looking for the optimal solution. I am just trying to solve using recursion for now. If n[i] is 0 I want the loop to go back to the previous loop and continue recursing, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
def jumpGame(self, n: []) -> bool:
    if len(n) < 2:
        return True
    for i in range(len(n)):                      
        for j in range(1, n[i]+1):
            next = i + j
            return self.jumpGame(n[next:])
    return False
```

Comment: A minor note - the word `next` in Python is reserved, and represents a function that will take the next value of an iterator. Best not to use it as a variable name! Unexpected behavior might result.

Comment: @TheThonnu - yours (the link post) is for *min jump*  a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do recursively and you said no need to be optimal ( so not memoized ), you could go with the below method. You don't need nested loops.
Also no need to explore all paths, you could optimize by looking at the step that you are going by checking `i + (jump) < n`

```py
def jumpGame(a, i):
  if i > len(a) - 1:
    return False
  if i == len(a) - 1:
    return True
  reached = False
  for j in range(1, a[i] + 1):
    if i + j < len(a):
      reached = jumpGame(a, i + j)
    if reached:
      return True
  return reached

print(jumpGame([2, 3, 1, 1, 4], 0))
print(jumpGame([3,2,1,0,4], 0))

True
False
```

Comment: `jumpGame([], 0, 0)` -> `IndexError: list index out of range.`

Comment: I would also note this is a particularly c-like approach, where passing in the index and the length of the array would be necessary. For Python both of those can be elided, since it's a zero-cost operation to get that information.

Comment: @NathanielFord I fixed the first issue. I understand that you don't need n as an extra parameter. But it is for learning purpose I assumed, but yet removed from my method signature.

Comment: I mean, you *also* don't need to track the index, since list slices will handle that for you just as efficiently. This fix also means your `if i + j < len(a)` is redundant in most cases.

Comment: I know python can slice list efficiently to return empty list but doing one more recursive call with empty list is completely unnecessary and those can be too many. Not to mention extra space needed for all those calls.

Answer (score 1):

When considering recursive solutions, the first thing you should consider is the 'base case', followed by the 'recursive case'. The base case is just 'what is the smallest form of this problem for which I can determine an answer', and the recursive is 'can I get from some form n of this problem to some form n - 1'.

That's a bit pedantic, but lets apply it to your situation. What is the base case? That case is if you have a list of length 1. If you have a list of length 0, there is no last index and you can return false. That would simply be:

```
if len(ls) == 0:
  return False
if len(ls) == 1:
  return True
```

Since we don't care what is in the last index, only at arriving at the last index, we know these if statements handle our base case.

Now for the recursive step. Assuming you have a list of length n, we must consider how to reduce the size of the problem. This is by making a 'jump', and we know that we can make a jump equal to a length up to the value of the current index. Then we just need to test each of these lengths. If any of them return `True`, we succeed.

```
any(jump_game(n[jump:] for jump in range(1, n[0] + 1)))
```

There are two mechanisms we are using here to make this easy. `any` takes in a sequence and quits as soon as one value is `True`, returning `True`. If none of them are true, it will return `False`. The second is a list slice, `n[jump:]` which takes a slice of a list from the index `jump` to the end. This might result in an empty list.

Putting this together we get:

```
def jump_game(n: list) -> bool:
  # Base cases
  if len(n) == 0:
    return False
  if len(n) == 1:
    return True
  # Recursive case
  return any(jump_game(n[jump:]) for jump in range(1, n[0] + 1))
```

The results:

```
>>> jump_game([2,3,1,1,4])
True
>>> jump_game([3,2,1,0,1])
False
>>> jump_game([])
False
>>> jump_game([1])
True
```

I'm trying to lay out the rigorous approach here, because I think it helps to clarify where recursion goes wrong. In your recursive case you do need to iterate through your options - but that is only one loop, not the two you have. In your solution, in *each* recursion, you're iterating (`for i in range(len(n))`) through the entire list. So, you're really hiding an iterative solution inside a recursive one. Further, your base case is wrong, because a list of length 0 is considered a valid solution - but in fact, only a list of length 1 should return a True result.

What you should focus on for recursion is, again, solving the smallest possible form(s) of the problem. Here, it is if the list is one or zero length long. Then, you need to step each other possible size of the problem (length of the list) to a base case. We know we can do that by examining the first element, and choosing to jump anywhere up to that value. This gives us our options. We try each in turn until a solution is found - or until the space is exhausted and we can confidently say there is no solution.